# Convert mwArray to std::vector<double>

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, shared-libraries, feature-extraction

I am using a feature matching algorithm that is coded in Matlab. I created shared libraries for C++ using the Library Compiler of Matlab.
As a result I am getting a mwArray consisting of n feature points and the point coordinates x,y (n rows, 2 cols). Now I would like to convert the mwArray into a `std::vector<double>` or even better a `std::vector<cv::Point2d>` so I can proceed.

I tried using the methods `GetData()` but I don't know which arguments I have to use.
Here is the code:

```
mclmcrInitialize();
    //const char *args[] = { "-nojvm" };
    //const int count = sizeof(args) / sizeof(args[0]);
    if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL, 0)) {

        std::cerr << "Could not initialize the application properly" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (!MatchingInitialize()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not initialize the library properly" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        try {

            // Create the output arrays
            mwArray FSC_1, FSC_2, NBCS_1, NBCS_2;
            mwArray path_1 = "C:\\test\\img_1.jpg";
            mwArray path_2 = "C:\\test\\img_2.jpg";
            Matching(1, FSC_1, FSC_2, NBCS_1, NBCS_2, path_1, path_2);



            // Output that works            
            std::cout << "The value is " << FSC_1 << std::endl;

            // Conversions I tried
            double *FSC_1_Copy = mxGetPr(FSC_1.GetData());

            std::vector<double> FSC_1_Copy = FSC_1.GetData();

            std::vector<double> data_copy;
            FSC_1.GetData(data_copy, FSC_1.RowIndex());

        }
        catch (const mwException& e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            return -2;
        }
        catch (...) {
            std::cerr << "Unexpected error thrown" << std::endl;
            return -3;
        }
        MatchingTerminate();

    }
```

Comment: In C++, I do: `float  *  var_C= static_cast<float  *>(mxGetData(var_matlab));`. Maybe somethign similar for `std::vector<double>` is possible. I doubt you can cast to `Point2D` though.

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes I realized while I added the comment, my mistake, I was doing it with C before.

Comment: Trying something like `double *FSC_1_Copy = static_cast<double *>(mxGetData(FSC_1));` I get the error `no suitable conversion function from "mwArray" to "const mwArray" exists`

Comment: indeed `FDC_1` has to be `const`. In my particular case I grab it from MATLAB and define it as: `mxArray const * const var_matlab= prhs[0];`

Comment: I don't understand the code. `FSC_1.GetData()` should have return type `void`. Is this reference correct: https://de.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/cxx/mwarray.html? `double *FSC_1_Copy = new double[FSC_1.NumberOfElements()]; FSC_1.GetData(FSC_1_Copy, FSC_1.NumberOfElements()); delete[] FSC_1_Copy;`

Comment: Yes, the reference is correct. I just wanted to show you what I have already tried but I am having problems understanding the arguments of the methods `GetData()` and `Get()`. Especially what do I have to fill in for `<numeric-type>* buffer, mwSize len` since I don't know the size at the point of creating my `mwArray`. All the conversions I tried throw exceptions. Sorry for the confusion. Edit: You were faster ;)

Comment: You can also try `std::vector<double> FSC_1_Copy(FSC_1.NumberOfElements()); FSC_1.GetData(FSC_1_Copy.data(), FSC_1.NumberOfElements());`

Comment: @Thomas Sablik Your last comment works like a charm. If you want to give the answer I will mark it as correct. I just have to split the `std::vector<double>` in the middle and get my x and y values. Thanks!
Btw.: I looked for a method called Size, Length or something but did not find NumberOfElements :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the matrix into a vector with

```
// Create a vector with size FSC_1.NumberOfElements()
// FSC_1_Copy allocates memory for an array
std::vector<double> FSC_1_Copy(FSC_1.NumberOfElements());

// Copy up to FSC_1.NumberOfElements() elements from FSC_1 into
// the array of FSC_1_Copy
FSC_1.GetData(FSC_1_Copy.data(), FSC_1.NumberOfElements());
```